# SharePoint Online: Is it possible to have an announcement from a team sub-site published to all sub-sites?

Tags: web-part, online

1st Post-
    My question is something that I am trying to resolve. I am a "sharepoint newbie" and I am a Network Technician by trade, so I am out of league. I have created Team Cite for my organization with sub-sites for each department. As part of this, I have created a Site Wide Announcement App, that I duplicated on all of the sub-sites. The announcement needs something that I could have certain users be able to add/edit and could "pushed" to all of the sub-sites quickly and easily. The need is to be able to get out word that an organization event is occurring, meeting or an emergency, etc... Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually in SharePoint you do the other way around, any department writes their own announcements in their own sites or subsites and they are all collated together on the main page of the intranet via content search web part, content query web part or search results. This saves up time and effort since it is a consolidated way that has been around for a decade.

If you want to keep your scenario as it is and not follow what is the most common way to disseminate news based on what I wrote above, you should put a content search web part in every site that has basically the same settings (which is to retrieve announcements from anywhere or announcements tagged in a certain way - details of the query will be up to you)

Comment: I am sorry for not replying to this right away. How do I do the latter? How would I configure a department site to be able to create and publish Announcements to the remaining department sites? I have been trying to find this on my own, have come up empty. Thanks

Comment: I repeat this is not the most common sense approach. You create an announcement list (only one). You follow a good guide about the content search web part (http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/03/displaying-right-data-in-content-search.html - in your announcement list the image is optional) and you place in every other site you want the news to be displayed in, the content search web part, note that they have to be configured one by one with the same details inside.